Alerts from Wazuh to Telegram stopped working after adding ChatGPT
I am working on sending alerts from Wazuh to Telegram and have integrated ChatGPT to include recommendations in the alerts before they are sent. The integration was working fine before adding ChatGPT, but now the alerts are not being sent. When I test the functions individually, they work as expected, but when combined, the alerts don't go through. All API keys are correct. I would appreciate any help or suggestions.
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import json
import requests
from datetime import datetime
import openai  # Ensure openai module is imported

# CHAT_ID="xxxx"
CHAT_ID = "00000000"

# AbuseIPDB API keys list
ABUSEIPDB_API_KEYS = [
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",  # Replace with your actual API keys
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
]

# OpenAI API key
openai.api_key = "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"

# Index to keep track of which API key to use
current_api_key_index = 0

# Malicious IP file path
MALICIOUS_IP_FILE = "/var/ossec/logs/malicious_ips.txt"

# Read configuration parameters
try:
    with open(sys.argv[1], encoding='utf-8') as alert_file:
        alert_json = json.load(alert_file)
except Exception as e:
    with open('/var/ossec/logs/integrations.log', 'a', encoding="utf-8") as log_file:
        log_file.write(f"Error reading alert file: {e}\n")
    sys.exit(1)

hook_url = sys.argv[3]  # URL for sending the alert

# Function to get the current API key based on round-robin rotation
def get_next_api_key():
    global current_api_key_index
    api_key = ABUSEIPDB_API_KEYS[current_api_key_index]
    # Move to the next key in the list (round-robin)
    current_api_key_index = (current_api_key_index + 1) % len(ABUSEIPDB_API_KEYS)
    return api_key

def get_location_from_ip(srcip):
    # Define the URL of the geolocation API (ipinfo.io in this case)
    url = f"https://ipinfo.io/{srcip}/json"

    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        response.raise_for_status()  # Check for request errors

        # Parse the JSON response
        data = response.json()

        # Extract country and city name
        country = data.get('country', 'N/A')
        city = data.get('city', 'N/A')

        # Return both country and city names
        return country, city

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Error fetching geolocation for {srcip}: {e}")
        return 'N/A', 'N/A'

def check_ip_malicious(srcip):
    """
    Check if the IP is malicious using AbuseIPDB's API with round-robin key rotation.
    """
    url = f"https://api.abuseipdb.com/api/v2/check"
    api_key = get_next_api_key()  # Get the next API key using round-robin
    headers = {
        'Key': api_key,
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
    params = {
        'ipAddress': srcip,
        'maxAgeInDays': 90  # Check only the last 90 days of reports
    }

    try:
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
        response.raise_for_status()

        data = response.json()

        # Check if the IP is flagged as malicious
        if data['data']['abuseConfidenceScore'] >= 50:  # If score is 50 or higher, consider as malicious
            return True
        return False

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Error checking IP {srcip} with AbuseIPDB: {e}")
        return False

def save_malicious_ip(srcip, country, city):
    """
    Save malicious IP along with country and city to a file.
    """
    timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    with open(MALICIOUS_IP_FILE, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(f"{timestamp} - IP: {srcip}, Country: {country}, City: {city}\n")

# Function to get recommendations from ChatGPT based on the source IP and rule description
def get_chatgpt_recommendation(ip, description):
    try:
        # Send the request to OpenAI's ChatGPT model
        response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
            model="gpt-3.5-turbo",  # Specify the chat model
            messages=[{"role": "system", "content": "You are a cybersecurity assistant providing detailed recommendations."},
                      {"role": "user", "content": f"Please provide recommendations based on the following rule description:\n\n{description}"}],
            max_tokens=150,  # Limit the length of the response
            temperature=0.7,  # Adjust for creativity or variability
        )

        # Extract and return the assistant's reply
        return response['choices'][0]['message']['content'].strip()

    except openai.error.OpenAIError as e:
        return f"An error occurred while fetching recommendations: {str(e)}"

# Extract data fields safely
alert_level = alert_json.get('rule', {}).get('level', 0)  # Assuming level is an integer, default to 0
description = alert_json.get('rule', {}).get('description', "N/A")
agent = alert_json.get('agent', {}).get('name', "N/A")
username = alert_json.get('data', {}).get('dstuser', alert_json.get('data', {}).get('srcuser', "N/A"))
sourceip = alert_json.get('data', {}).get('srcip', alert_json.get('data', {}).get('src_ip', "N/A"))

# Try fetching geolocation and malicious status
try:
    country, city = get_location_from_ip(sourceip)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error fetching geolocation for {sourceip}, falling back to ChatGPT: {e}")
    country, city = 'N/A', 'N/A'

try:
    is_malicious = check_ip_malicious(sourceip)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error checking if {sourceip} is malicious, falling back to ChatGPT: {e}")
    is_malicious = False

# Get recommendation from ChatGPT
chatgpt_recommendation = get_chatgpt_recommendation(sourceip, description)

# Print the result
print(f"Source IP: {sourceip}")
print(f"Country for IP {sourceip}: {country}")
print(f"City for IP {sourceip}: {city}")
print(f"Is the IP malicious? {'Yes' if is_malicious else 'No'}")
print(f"ChatGPT Recommendation: {chatgpt_recommendation}")

# If the IP is malicious, save it to the file
if is_malicious:
    save_malicious_ip(sourceip, country, city)

# If the alert level is lower than 5, skip sending to Telegram
if alert_level < 5:
    print(f"Alert level is {alert_level}. Skipping sending to Telegram.")
    sys.exit(0)

# Generate request message
msg_text = (
    f"*Уровень тревоги*: {alert_level}\n"
    f"*Описание*: {description}\n"
    f"*Источник*: {agent}\n"
    f"*Пользователь*: {username}\n"
    f"*Удаленный хост*: {sourceip}\n"
    f"*Местоположение*: {city}, {country}\n"
    f"*Возможно IP-адрес удаленного хоста является вредоносным?*: {'Да' if is_malicious else 'Нет'}\n"
    f"*Рекомендация ChatGPT*: {chatgpt_recommendation}\n"
)

# Generate request data
msg_data = {
    "chat_id": CHAT_ID,
    "text": msg_text,
}

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept-Charset': 'UTF-8'}

# Send the request
try:
    print(f"Sending message: {json.dumps(msg_data, indent=2)}")
    response = requests.post(hook_url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(msg_data), params={"parse_mode": "Markdown"})
    response.raise_for_status()  # Raise an exception for HTTP errors
except Exception as e:
    with open('/var/ossec/logs/integrations.log', 'a', encoding="utf-8") as log_file:
        log_file.write(f"Error sending alert: {e}\n")
    sys.exit(1)

# Log the response for debugging
if response.status_code != 200:
    with open('/var/ossec/logs/integrations.log', 'a', encoding="utf-8") as log_file:
        log_file.write(f"Error sending message: {response.status_code} - {response.text}\n")
else:
    with open('/var/ossec/logs/integrations.log', 'a', encoding="utf-8") as log_file:
        log_file.write(f"Message sent successfully: {response.status_code}\n")

sys.exit(0)


I tested the script without the ChatGPT integration, and it worked fine. However, when ChatGPT is included, the alerts aren't being sent. When I use a different script for ChatGPT, it works as expected.
